# When rotating an object with a 3d css transform, how to keep the direction constant i.e. go 'over the top' rather than backwards

Tags: css

When applying a 3D transform with a transition animation, is there a way to rotate from a high deg to a lower one forwards, so that I can rotate for example from 350deg to 10deg by moving forwards 20deg not moving backwards 340deg.

Comment: Does using 370deg (or -10deg) work?

Comment: yes 370deg works, i will just keep adding degrees, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick test and it seems to work with negative values :)

*([src](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_rotateY))*

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(40deg); /* Safari prior 9.0 */
  transform: rotateY(40deg); /* Standard syntax */
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#myDiv:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-30deg); /* Safari prior 9.0 */
  transform: rotateY(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
40 to -30deg rotated element.
</div>
```